# How create custome spring scope which provide beans similar to session scope?

Tags: java, spring, custom-scope

It is needed to define Spring scope which will provide a proxy to the beans and reload/recreate target beans when say an event occurs. The behavior is similar to session beans, except there is no http session.

Does Spring provide a way for such bean proxing and scope manipulation?

**UPDATED**

Say that it is need to change `externalUrl` which is used to send http requests. So the application has to switch to new bean with new http connection pool created.

When bean autowired directly it is imposible to recreate it, especially when it is used in many places. So I search some way to inject a proxy instead of it and recreate target instace without altering caller code.

Comment: It would probably be best to explain your use case in more detail. Spring Cloud Config sounds like it might be what you need.

Comment: Question was updated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I can't tell you exactly how to do it, but if you're able to, something like [Spring Cloud Config](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/docs/1.0.x/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope) would be exactly what you want. If you can't adopt that, I would start digging into the source code. The class you'd want to start with is the [`RefreshScope`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/context/scope/refresh/RefreshScope.java) - from there, you should be able to figure out how it works and how it re-creates beans. I'm sorry that I can't provide more direction.